# Angular Service testing with http and other dependencies

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-httpclient, angular-test

I have written a wrapper for httpclient which sets the config from the observable and also uses toastr in case of error. It doesn't fail when the other two constructor injections are removed.

In case I mock RestService, I cant use `HttpTestingController` which provides other useful methods for httpclient testing

**rest.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class RestService {
    public baseUrl = null;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private appConfigService: AppConfigService,
        private toast: ToastNotificationService,
    ) {
        this.getConfig();
    }

    get<T>(url, showError = true): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<T>(this.baseUrl + url).pipe(
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                return this.showError(error, showError);
            }),
        );
    }

    private getConfig() {
        this.appConfigService.appConfig$.subscribe(env => {
            this.baseUrl = env.backendUrl + API_PREFIX;
        });
    }

    private showError(error: HttpErrorResponse, showError) {
        let message = Helpers.getErrorMessageFromObject(error);
        if (showError && message) this.toast.showError(message);

        return throwError(error);
    }   
}
```

**rest.service.spec.ts**

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { AppConfigService } from './app-config.service';
import { RestService } from './rest.service';
import { ToastNotificationService } from './toast-notification.service';

describe('RestService', () => {
    let service: RestService;
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
    const testData = { name: 'Test Data' };

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [
                RestService,
                {
                    provide: AppConfigService,
                    useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj({
                        appConfig$: of(),
                    }),
                },
                {
                    provide: ToastNotificationService,
                    useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj({
                        showError: function () { },
                    }),
                },
            ],
        });

        service = TestBed.get(RestService);
        httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        httpMock.verify();
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should get the data successful', () => {
        service.baseUrl = '';
        const endpoint = '/api/v1/features/1';

        service.get(endpoint).subscribe((data: any) => {
            expect(data).toEqual(testData);
            expect(service.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(service.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(endpoint);
        });

        const req = httpMock.expectOne(endpoint);
        expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
        req.flush(testData);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `HttpTestingController`? You already added one layer of abstraction. In your services' perspective, they don't know what's going on under the hood. They shouldn't try to use `HttpTestingController`

Comment: I don't get what your question is. Everywhere where you will use `RestService` (since it is already tested), you can mock its public methods using `jasmine.createSpyObj`.